# tableLayoutPanel column width

Tags: .net, winforms, ironpython, tablelayoutpanel

I created a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) and I would like to reduce the width of one of the columns. Is TableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles  the way to go? I find the MSDN documentation confusing. How do I apply tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyle?

```
self.tableLayoutPanel.Location = Point(20,80)
self.tableLayoutPanel.Size = Size(200,50)
self.tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 2
self.tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 6
self.tableLayoutPanel.AutoSize = True
self.tableLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = False
self.tableLayoutPanel.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Outset
#self.tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles = ??
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the column style and row style to each column and row:

Example:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To self.tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount - 1
  self.tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 64))
Next
For i As Integer = 0 To self.tableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 1
  self.tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 24))
Next
```